# Python regex with variable {}-multiplier

Tags: python, regex

Say you wanted to create a pattern that matches sequences of `var` consecutive digits. You could do it this way:

```
p = re.compile(r"\d{"+str(var)+"}")
```

or this way:

```
p = re.compile(r"\d{%d}" % var)
```

But how would you do it using format()?

I tried both:

```
p = re.compile(r"\d{0}".format(var))
```

and:

```
p = re.compile(r"\d{{0}}".format(var))
```

but none of these worked.

Comment: I'd just like to add that there's nothing *wrong* per se with using `%`, even though `.format` is generally better.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You need to actually have triple `{` and `}` - two for the escaped literal braces and one for the placeholder:

```
In [1]: var = 6

In [2]: r"\d{{{0}}}".format(var)
Out[2]: '\\d{6}'
```